# "names.default_domain = world" not being set when looking up tnsnames.ora

Tags: java, oracle

I have a requirement for my java application to connect to an Oracle database (10 and 11g) using the Oracle wallet for the DB credentials.

My issue is when connecting trying to connect to the database i get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: could not resolve the connect identifier "mydb".
```

sqlnet.ora looks like the following:

```
AUTOMATIC_IPC = OFF
TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT = OFF
names.directory_path = (TNSNAMES)
names.default_domain = world
names.default_zone = world


WALLET_LOCATION =
 (SOURCE =
 (METHOD = FILE)
 (METHOD_DATA =
   (DIRECTORY = <wallet location C:....>)
 )
)

SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE = TRUE
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSESSL_VERSION = 0
```

And my tnsnames.ora entry looks like:

```
mydb.WORLD =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (Host = <HOST>)
    (Port = <PORT>))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SERVICE_NAME = <DB_SERVICES>)
  (INSTANCE_NAME = mydb)
 )
)
```

and my wallet entry is setup as follows:

```
mkstore -wrl C:\oracle\wallet -createCredential mydb username "password"
```

Java application connection string as follows:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:/@mydb
```

Now the connection works if the `.world` is removed from the entry in tnsnames.ora, but from my understanding that is what the `names.default_domain = world` should pass to the tnsnames.ora lookup, is that correct? if so then why isn't this being set?
I can connect to sqlplus in dos fine by using sqlplus /@mydb

Thanks

Comment: I can't see anything in the docs about JDBC using `sqlnet.ora`, but it does honour the default domain when using the OCI client. It does not seem to when using the thin client (with the `-Doracle.net.tns_admin` flag), regardless of the wallet being in the picture. So it seems to be a limitation of the thin driver? It all works if the alias is used everywhere - the wallet credential is `mydb.world`, and the JDBC URL is `jdbc:oracle:thin:/@mydb.world`. It sounds like you're trying to avoid that; but won't the URL come from a parameter anyway?

Comment: Yes, I can't use the alias everywhere and yes the database name is passed as a paramater but i can't pass the alias or set it in a properties file in java as it doesn't pick up the credentials from the wallet as the wallet is setup with mydb not mydb.world and its not an option to setup the wallet with mydb.world. Initially i did try the connection using the OCI client but this caused errors with java about native libraries - Looks like i would need to use the OCI client and try and get around the native issues?

Comment: OCI would get around it, yes, from a bit of testing. You can have entries for both `mydb` and `mydb.world` in the wallet at the same time, if that's an issue; if Java used `mydb.world` that woudl work, and SQL*Plus could still use `mydb` (picking up the default domain). A different version of the driver might fix this too but I haven't investigated that.

Comment: Ok thanks for your time Alex - btw another option we're looking into is to build the java as java stored procs in the database, eliminating the connection OR using the built in packages in pl/sql to parse an xml as that is all the java is used for.